# C# BinaryReader ReadBytes(len) returns different results than Read(bytes, 0, len)

Tags: c#, binaryreader

I've got a BinaryReader reading in a number of bytes into an array. The underlying Stream for the reader is a BufferedStream(whose underlying stream is a network stream). I noticed that sometimes the `reader.Read(arr, 0, len)` method is returning different(wrong) results than `reader.ReadBytes(len)`.

Basically my setup code looks like this:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var reader = new BinaryReader(new BufferedStream(await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false)));
```

Later on down the line, I'm reading a byte array from the reader. I can confirm the sz variable is the same for both scenarios.

```
int sz = ReadSize(reader); //sz of the array to read
if (bytes == null || bytes.Length <= sz)
{
    bytes = new byte[sz];
}

//reader.Read will return different results than reader.ReadBytes sometimes
//everything else is the same up until this point
//var tempBytes = reader.ReadBytes(sz); <- this will return right results
reader.Read(bytes, 0, sz); // <- this will not return the right results sometimes
```

It seems like the reader.Read method is reading further into the stream than it needs to or something, because the rest of the parsing will break after this happens. Obviously I could stick with reader.ReadBytes, but I want to reuse the byte array to go easy on the GC here.

Would there ever be any reason that this would happen? Is a setting wrong or something?

Comment: Might be something related to the fact that it's a network stream? When you create the new byte array you "freeze" a little part of the stream, but when you later parse that "freezed" stream with the rest of it it won't match. Caution: never worked with network stream, totally flying by my pants :)

Comment: Under which condition `ReadBytes` can read less bytes then requested? Under which condition `Read` can read less bytes then requested? How this conditions different?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you clear out `bytes` array before calling this function because `Read(bytes, 0, len)` does NOT clear given byte array, so some previous bytes may conflict with new one. I also had this problem long ago in one of my parsers. just set all elements to zero, or make sure that you are only reading (parsing) up to given `len`